# How to update existing records

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a location table with hierarchy :

> Country > State > City > Site

Location Name is Unique.
LOCATION2PARENTLOCATION column has hierarchy relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE "LOCATION" 
   ("LOCATIONID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "ALIAS1" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "TOWNCITY" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "LOCATION2PARENTLOCATION" NUMBER,
    "LOCATION2LOCATIONTYPE" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    CONSTRAINT location_id_pk   PRIMARY KEY (LOCATIONID),
    CONSTRAINT location_name_uq UNIQUE(NAME)
   );
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (1,'India',null,null,null,null,null,'COUNTRY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (2,'Bihar','BH',null,null,null,1,'STATE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (3,'Maharashtra','MH',null,null,null,1,'STATE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (4,'Aurangabad',null,null,null,null,2,'CITY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (5,'Patna',null,null,null,null,2,'CITY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (6,'Pune',null,null,null,null,3,'CITY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (8,'Aurangabad,BH',null,null,null,null,2,'CITY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (9,'Aurangabad,MH',null,null,null,null,3,'CITY');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (10,'Deo',null,'Aurangabad','Bihar','India',4,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (11,'Obra',null,'Aurangabad','Bihar','India',4,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (12,'Kutumba',null,'Aurangabad,BH','Bihar','India',8,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (13,'Dura',null,'Aurangabad,BH','Bihar','India',8,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (14,'Dhanpura',null,'Patna','Bihar','India',5,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (15,'Shekhpura',null,'Patna','Bihar','India',5,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (16,'Hadapsar',null,'Pune','Maharashtra','India',6,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (17,'Baner',null,'Pune','Maharashtra','India',6,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (18,'Cidco',null,'Aurangabad,MH','Maharashtra','India',9,'SITE');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (19,'Mukundwadi',null,'Aurangabad,MH','Maharashtra','India',9,'SITE');
```

> Problem Statement:

There are some City names which are common among multiple States.

For eg. Aurangabad is a City in Maharashtra and Bihar, like many other examples.
Since Name is unique so table won't allow me to insert duplicate city name in Location Table with hierarchy.

> Solution of the problem:

In order to maintain hierarchy among location, I have decided to append State code (Alias1 column of State) in city Name.
Which will be a unique Name.

For. eg.

- Patna City will be updated with 'Patna,BH'
- Pune with 'Pune,MH'
- Aurangabad from Bihar will be updated with 'Aurangabad,BH'
- Aurangabad from Maharashtra will be updated with 'Aurangabad,MH'

> SQL Problem:

I want to updated all city name with 'City,StateCode' in old existing records.
But there are some Cities already created with 'Aurangabad' and 'Aurangabad,BH' both under same state.
which are not allow me to update old existing record.

```
UPDATE LOCATION L1
SET L1.NAME= L1.NAME ||','||(SELECT L2.ALIAS1 FROM LOCATION L2 WHERE L1.location2parentlocation = L2.LOCATIONID AND L2.location2LOCATIONTYPE='STATE')
WHERE L1.location2locationtype='CITY'
and L1.name not like '%,%';

UPDATE LOCATION L10
SET TOWNCITY= (SELECT NAME FROM LOCATION L11  WHERE L11.LOCATIONID=L10.location2parentlocation AND L11.location2LOCATIONTYPE='CITY')
WHERE L10.LOCATION2LOCATIONTYPE='SITE';


Oracle Error:
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (LOCATION_NAME_UQ) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

If I delete records with 'City,StateCode', above update statement will work, But I don't wish to delete any record.

```
delete from location where locationid in (8,9,12,13,18,19);
```

> ```
> Question:
> ```

How do I updated old existing records and maintain hierarchy relationship.

Comment: A better solution is to make the primary key be (LOCATION, STATE), not to add the name of the state to the location name.

Comment: Thanks @Bob, I can not change the table structure due to some product limitation :( . The only thing is I have to play with the data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't wish to delete any record.

It seems to me that you truly have duplicate data.  LOCATIONID 4 and LOCATIONID 8 truly represent the same city and one of them should go.

If that is correct, it is first necessary to consolidate the SITE records for cities 4 and 8 under one ID.  Then we can delete the other.

Here is a `MERGE` statement (with comments) that does all that.

It basically figures out how we want to rename and renumber the cities, identifying the lowest city ID with a given name & state as the one we will keep.  It will consolidate the site records under the cities that will be kept and deletes the cities that are duplicates and no longer needed.

```
MERGE INTO location t
USING (
-- This query will list each location along with (for cities and sites) the new city name and city ID to use
WITH city_rename AS (
SELECT city.locationid, 
       city.name city_name, 
       state.name state_name, 
       state.alias1 state_alias1, 
       case when city.name like '%,' || state.alias1 THEN city.name ELSE city.name || ',' || state.alias1 END new_city_name,
       row_number() over ( partition by case when city.name like '%,' || state.alias1 THEN city.name ELSE city.name || ',' || state.alias1 END order by city.locationid ) rn,
       min(city.locationid) over ( partition by case when city.name like '%,' || state.alias1 THEN city.name ELSE city.name || ',' || state.alias1 END order by city.locationid ) new_city_id
FROM   location city
INNER JOIN location state ON state.locationid = city.location2parentlocation
WHERE  city.location2locationtype = 'CITY' )
SELECT l.*, cr.new_city_name, cr.new_city_id FROM location l
LEFT JOIN city_rename cr ON cr.locationid IN (l.locationid, l.location2parentlocation) ) u
ON ( t.locationid = u.locationid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
-- Update each CITY and SITE record according to the city renaming results above
UPDATE SET
   -- Rename the city
   t.name = CASE WHEN t.location2locationtype = 'CITY' THEN u.new_city_name ELSE t.name END,
   -- Redirect the sites to the unique city ID for the new city name
   t.location2parentlocation = CASE WHEN t.location2locationtype = 'SITE' THEN u.new_city_id ELSE t.location2parentlocation END,
   -- Rename the towncity for the sites
   t.towncity = CASE WHEN t.location2locationtype = 'SITE' THEN u.new_city_name ELSE t.towncity END
-- Finally, as part of the MERGE, delete any cities that are not unique for the new city name.  Any SITE records 
-- previously tied to this city will have been redirect to the main ID for the new city name by the above logic
DELETE WHERE t.location2locationtype = 'CITY' and u.new_city_id != t.locationid;
```

After the above `MERGE` your `LOCATION` table looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| LOCATIONID |     NAME      | ALIAS1 |   TOWNCITY    |    STATE    | COUNTRY | LOCATION2PARENTLOCATION | LOCATION2LOCATIONTYPE |
+------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
|          1 | India         |  -     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                      -  | COUNTRY               |
|          2 | Bihar         | BH     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       1 | STATE                 |
|          3 | Maharashtra   | MH     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       1 | STATE                 |
|          4 | Aurangabad,BH |  -     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       2 | CITY                  |
|          5 | Patna,BH      |  -     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       2 | CITY                  |
|          6 | Pune,MH       |  -     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       3 | CITY                  |
|          9 | Aurangabad,MH |  -     |  -            |  -          |  -      |                       3 | CITY                  |
|         10 | Deo           |  -     | Aurangabad,BH | Bihar       | India   |                       4 | SITE                  |
|         11 | Obra          |  -     | Aurangabad,BH | Bihar       | India   |                       4 | SITE                  |
|         12 | Kutumba       |  -     | Aurangabad,BH | Bihar       | India   |                       4 | SITE                  |
|         13 | Dura          |  -     | Aurangabad,BH | Bihar       | India   |                       4 | SITE                  |
|         14 | Dhanpura      |  -     | Patna,BH      | Bihar       | India   |                       5 | SITE                  |
|         15 | Shekhpura     |  -     | Patna,BH      | Bihar       | India   |                       5 | SITE                  |
|         16 | Hadapsar      |  -     | Pune,MH       | Maharashtra | India   |                       6 | SITE                 |
|         17 | Baner         |  -     | Pune,MH       | Maharashtra | India   |                       6 | SITE                 |
|         18 | Cidco         |  -     | Aurangabad,MH | Maharashtra | India   |                       9 | SITE                 |
|         19 | Mukundwadi    |  -     | Aurangabad,MH | Maharashtra | India   |                       9 | SITE                 |
+------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Notice how LOCATIONID 8 is gone and all the records previously referring to it now refer to LOCATIONID 4.

Comment: Many many thanks to @Matthew McPeak, It worked as per my expectation.